# Problem in selecting row of table in view subclass technique

Tags: iphone

In my application i have table view cells.When i select one cell it takes me corresponding views according to selected cells. I have implemented it using custom subclass of UITableViewCell i.e. subclassing of cells with nib file rather then subviews using code.

I used NSDictionary to feed my cells data like below on viewDidLoad method

```
NSDictionary *row1=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mac", @"Name", @"1.5", @"Rate", nil];

NSDictionary *row2=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"MINI", @"Name", @"14.4",@"Rate", nil];  NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:row1, row2 nil];
self.computers=array;
```

and in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method i use

```
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (childController==nil) {
    childController=[[computerConverter alloc]initWithNibName:@"computerController" bundle:nil];

    childController.title=@"Select computer to convert";
    NSUInteger row=[indexPath row];
    NSString *selectedComputer=[self.computers objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *detailMassage=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",selectedComputer];
    childController.massage =detailMassage;
    childController.title=selectedComputer;
    [detailMassage release];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];
    childController =nil;
}
```

}

It shows NSException and does not take me to another corresponding view. Any suggestion will highly appreciated.

Comment: a) What does the backtrace show you for the exception? b) That is some very leaky code. I take it you're not running the static analyser. e.g `childController = nil` should really be `self.childController = nil`

Comment: Yes the thing is i have just put some of my code here. i did all memory management things. i think problem is with childController or with Dictionary elements.  It cant be self.childController because childController is not this class's object. It is object of next class where we will go after clicking any cell.

Comment: row1 and row2 are dictionaries and hence you cannot do this

    childController.title=selectedComputer;

You may want to set the returned value for a key from this dictionary. I guess the problem is in the above line.

Comment: Yes mate the problem is this. Because when i commented out this thing it runs good, But i want to show data from each cell clicked in childController class i.e. next view that it takes to me. So what you reckon what should i do

Comment: @Praveen S, You are genius mate. The problem was with exactly that line. All sorted. Thanks. Put this in your answer. I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: @Praveen S, If you have a time will you have a look on my other problem i.e. Q. using composition to access values of two different variables? I have posted this question 2 days ago but till date cant get proper answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok i have added that as an answer.

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking in your other question.

Comment: @Praveen S My question is: I have a class A having textFieldA and class B having textFieldB.

I want to access values of textFieldA and textFieldB into class C and wants to show in label.  Problem is i have accessed textFieldA and textFieldB in classC by using there objects in classC. but i does not show the values of textFieldA and B in label C

Comment: Class and objects are different. So my first question is how are the values in classA and classB set?

Comment: These values are filled in textFieldA in classA and textFieldB in class B. These are textFields.and then i saved them using userDefault method

Comment: @Parveen S Have you got any idea how to do this. I am straggling with this for long. I really appreciate if you will suggest me something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

row1 and row2 are dictionaries and hence you cannot do this

```
childController.title=selectedComputer;
```

You may want to set the returned value for a key from this dictionary. I guess the problem is in the above line.